# Issue with white spaces in flat file in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch framework to parse a fixed length flat file using `FlatFileItemReader` with **lineMapper** as`DefaultLineMapper` and **fieldSetMapper** as PassThroughFieldSetMapper and **lineTokenizer** as PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer.

But I am facing some issue regarding the the processing since the values in the file may have white spaces. **FieldSet** is giving me the values after removing any leading or trailing white spaces. I want the values with whitespaces,if any, for some validation purpose.

I am new to Spring Batch framework. Can someone please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you share a line sample from your file, that shows also the split character.

Comment: I think Spring already has something for this: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer Isn't it good enough for it?

Answer (score 3):

I know it was asked long time ago but if anyone will have the same issue :

The problem is with FieldSet class, because when you call `fieldSet.readString()` it will call `readAndTrim()` method and return trimmed string.
To get your string with whitespaces preserved you should call `fieldSet.readRawString()`

Comment: Do you have an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

I also just want to give an answer to this problem:

You can create you own implementation of `FieldMapper` and autowire it to your `lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper()`

```
@Component
class CustomFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Partnership>{

    @Override
    public Partnership mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

        return new Partnership(
                partnerCrmId:fieldSet.readString('partnerCrmId'),
                partnerType: fieldSet.readString('partnerType'),
                customerCrmId: fieldSet.readString('customerCrmId'),
                startDate: fieldSet.readString('startDate'),
                endDate: fieldSet.readString('endDate'),
                clientId: fieldSet.readRawString('clientId'),
                status: fieldSet.readString('status'),
                type: fieldSet.readString('type'),
                providerCode: fieldSet.readString('providerCode'),
                lastModifiedDate: fieldSet.readString('lastModifiedDate')
        )

    }
}
```